# pass parameters on crystal report , connect access with code , vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, parameters, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I want to search clients that got to shop between two dates. 
The code I use seems alright and it doesn't return any error but the CR returns everything - It does not use the date search function. The CR I use is tested with a simple program that open CR and works fine.
database is ms access and code is in visual studio 2005

The second issue I have is that despite i use the connection info part it still ask me for a code 
PS. sorry for my bad formatting , i am new in stackoverflow and i find it hard to make a post 
thank you!
-Agisilaos

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class Form1
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()


 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument


cryRpt = New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\agis\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\new_contracts     _of_month\new_contracts _of_month\CrystalReport2.rpt",     CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)


With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = "C:\Users\agis\Desktop\Insurance database\Insurancemanager.mdb"
        .UserID = "Admin"
        .Password = "kos"
        .DatabaseName = "insurancemanager"
    End With

     'first parameter
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text) 

    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("startdate")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterValues.Clear()

    ' second parameter : 
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions2 As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition2 As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues2 As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue2 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    crParameterDiscreteValue2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text)
    TextBox3.Text += "   " + crParameterDiscreteValue2.Value 
    crParameterFieldDefinitions2 = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition2 = crParameterFieldDefinitions2.Item("enddate")
    crParameterValues2 = crParameterFieldDefinition2.CurrentValues
    crParameterValues2.Clear()


    crParameterValues2.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue2)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
    crParameterFieldDefinition2.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues2)
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
End Sub




    End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t understand what exactly your problem is but I assume that you want to pass parameter to report and filter report data on those parameters also want to set run-time connection settings of crystal report.

First create parameter field in your report (right click on parameter fields and click on add in crystal designer)
Now go to “crystal report->report->select expert” menu in visual studio crystal report designer and set data filter condition using these parameter fields.
For passing parameter to report use parameter name and value like this

```
cryRpt.ParameterFields("parametername").CurrentValues.AddValue(objVal)
cryRpt.ParameterFields("fromdatetime").CurrentValues.AddValue(Now)
```

you don’t have to set any server name for ms access database better way is create dsn for your database file and use that dsn in your report so your report will never ask for database file unless data file is missing you can even create dsn programmatically at run time if want that let us know
if you wat to set sql like server database password and login at runtime use

```
repDoc.DataSourceConnections(0).SetLogon("usrID","psw")                        
repDoc.DataSourceConnections(0).IntegratedSecurity = False
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It came out that there was something wrong with the report. But now i have another problem. It doesnt pass the parameteres. I get the prompt of CR for insert parameteres. Please advice  , thank you

Comment: parameter names are case Case sensitive

Comment: added/passed value object is null or empty

Comment: crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("startdate")   -my parameter is called startdate

Comment: TextBox3.Text += "   " + crParameterDiscreteValue2.Value  ' this return  the value i give

Comment: Oh i entered    crParameterValues2.Clear() before i pass values! thanks a lot friend!!!